# Setting up SSH authentication on openLDAP server

Tags: 16.04, ssh, login, ldap, pam

I have setup an Ubuntu 16.04 openLDAP server and want to allow LDAP users to login locally with SSH (to commit to a repository etc.) with `libnss` and `pam_ldap.so`.

Every time I login via ssh I get disconnected after entering the password with the message `connection closed by remote host`.

Steps I did:

- install `slapd` and `ldap-utils` on the server
- install `libnss-ldapd`, `libpam-ldapd` and `nslcd` also on the server since it also serves as the client

LDAP server is setup and user authentication works for several other services: GitLab, LDAP login with another Ubuntu system or Windows.

```
ldapsearch -h localhost -b ou=users,dc=example,dc=net -x uid=myuser
```

returns the expected output:

```
dn: cn=My User,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net
cn: xxx
givenName: My User
gidNumber: 502
homeDirectory: /home/users/myuser
sn: User
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
uidNumber: 1001
uid: myuser
loginShell: /bin/bash
```

Files look like the following:

`/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:         compat ldap
group:          compat ldap
shadow:         compat ldap
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000 use_first_pass debug
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-account`:

```
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
account requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
account required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
account sufficient                      pam_localuser.so
account [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore]    pam_sss.so
account [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=done ignore=ignore user_unknown=ignore authinfo_unavail=ignore default=bad]        pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
password        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3
password        [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
password        sufficient                      pam_sss.so use_authtok
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000 try_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
password        required                        pam_permit.so
```

The output from:

```
$ nslcd -d
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: connection from pid=12412 uid=0 gid=0
    nslcd: [8b4567] <protocol="ip"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=example,dc=net", filter="(&(objectClass=ipProtocol)(cn=ip))")
    nslcd: [8b4567] <protocol="ip"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://example.net)
    nslcd: [8b4567] <protocol="ip"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
    nslcd: [8b4567] <protocol="ip"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
    nslcd: [8b4567] <protocol="ip"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
    nslcd: [8b4567] <protocol="ip"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
    nslcd: [8b4567] <protocol="ip"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
    nslcd: [8b4567] <protocol="ip"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
    nslcd: [8b4567] <protocol="ip"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
    nslcd: [8b4567] <protocol="ip"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
    nslcd: [8b4567] <protocol="ip"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net","***") (uri="ldap://example.net")
    nslcd: [8b4567] <protocol="ip"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
    nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: connection from pid=12412 uid=0 gid=0
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=example,dc=net", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=myuser))")
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://example.net)
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net","***") (uri="ldap://example.net")
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=My User,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net
    nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
    nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: connection from pid=12412 uid=0 gid=0
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=example,dc=net", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=myuser))")
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://example.net)
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net","***") (uri="ldap://example.net")
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=My User,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net
    nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
    nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: connection from pid=12412 uid=0 gid=0
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=example,dc=net", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=myuser))")
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://example.net)
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net","***") (uri="ldap://example.net")
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=My User,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net
    nslcd: [334873] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
    nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: connection from pid=12412 uid=0 gid=0
    nslcd: DEBUG: accept() failed (ignored): Resource temporarily unavailable
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: nslcd_pam_authc("myuser","sshd","***")
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=example,dc=net", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=myuser))")
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=My User,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="cn=My User,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net", filter="(objectClass=*)")
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://example.net)
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_sasl_bind("cn=My User,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net","***") (uri="ldap://example.net")
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=My User,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_unbind()
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: bind successful
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=example,dc=net", filter="(&(objectClass=shadowAccount)(uid=myuser))")
    nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
    nslcd: [495cff] DEBUG: connection from pid=12412 uid=0 gid=0
    nslcd: DEBUG: accept() failed (ignored): Resource temporarily unavailable
    nslcd: [495cff] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=example,dc=net", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=myuser))")
    nslcd: [495cff] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=My User,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net
    nslcd: [495cff] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
    nslcd: [e8944a] DEBUG: connection from pid=12412 uid=0 gid=0
    nslcd: DEBUG: accept() failed (ignored): Resource temporarily unavailable
    nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=example,dc=net", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=myuser))")
    nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=My User,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net
    nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
    nslcd: [5558ec] DEBUG: connection from pid=12412 uid=0 gid=0
    nslcd: DEBUG: accept() failed (ignored): Resource temporarily unavailable
    nslcd: [5558ec] <authz="myuser"> DEBUG: nslcd_pam_authz("myuser","sshd","","192.168.0.1","ssh")
    nslcd: [5558ec] <authz="myuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=example,dc=net", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=myuser))")
    nslcd: [5558ec] <authz="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=My User,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net
    nslcd: [5558ec] <authz="myuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=example,dc=net", filter="(&(objectClass=shadowAccount)(uid=myuser))")
    nslcd: [5558ec] <authz="myuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
```

Having a look on the auth.log says:

```
sshd[14229]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.0.1  user=myuser
sshd[14229]: pam_ldap(sshd:auth): nslcd authentication; user=myuser
sshd[14229]: pam_ldap(sshd:auth): authentication succeeded
sshd[14229]: Failed password for myuser from 192.168.0.1 port 57734 ssh2
sshd[14229]: fatal: Access denied for user myuser by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

Running an own ssh daemon on port 4000 to debug outputs:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d -D -p 4000

Connection from 192.168.0.1 port 46728 on 192.168.0.2 port 4000
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 107/65534 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user myuser service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: initializing for "myuser"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.0.1"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user myuser service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: password authentication accepted for myuser
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Failed password for myuser from 192.168.0.1 port 46728 ssh2
Access denied for user myuser by PAM account configuration [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 14671
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
```

Where should I go next?

Comment: Did you forget to put a + in your /etc/passwd? Why are you using nss compat at all?

Comment: Also you seem to have nslcd and sssd active at the same time, which looks odd to me.

Comment: I did not touch the /etc/passwd at all. where is a + missing?

Comment: would you recommend to purge sssd?

Comment: I think compat was the default. Sorry I am really not very experienced. Just put everything together from several guides and tried to understand and debug.

Comment: ok, forget about the compat then :) I recommend to decide between nslcd and sssd, stick with only one of them and configure only it. pam-auth-update should fix your pam config perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! After removing sssd from the pam files it works! :)